# Can @Parameter method return Collection<List<String>> instead of Collection<String[]>?

Tags: java, junit4, parameterized

When I executed the Parameterized TestClass with this `@Parameter` method, I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - wrong number of arguments`  exception.

Code:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<List<String>> inputParameter(){
    Collection<List<String>> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> args1 = new ArrayList<>();
    args1.add("CD");
    args1.add("AACD");

    List<String> args2 = new ArrayList<>();
    args2.add("BCBC");
    args2.add("BCBC");

    parameters.add(args1);
    parameters.add(args2);

    return parameters;
}
```

Please help me understand the problem in this code. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand exactly what you want or what you are truly trying to accomplish but I'm willing to give it a go here. If you were to provide more information then you would most likely get a more in depth answer.

The code you supplied within your post is okay and will indeed compile, it's all a matter of how you call the method and then how you Iterate through the **inputParameter()** method returned results (Collection).

Because this method returns a Collection of Lists you need to declare a Collection to place that returned collection into:

```
Collection<List<String>> list = inputParameter();
```

There are several ways to iterate through a Collection. It all depends what you want from the Collection. I believe you just want to see what **each** list contains:

```
//Java 8 (sequential Stream):
list.forEach((temp) -> {
    System.out.println(temp);
});
```

The console output will be:

```
[CD, AACD]
[BCBC, BCBC]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think my question is not very clear; so I would like to restate it. As you see in my code, the return type of my @Parameters method is Collection<List<String>>. When Collection<List<String>> is specified as return type, I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException; but when I modify my code to return Collection<String[]>, I do not get any exception. I am curious to know the reason for this behavior.